# Installing Scrapy throws exceptions again and again

Tags: python, scrapy, pip

I've tried to install  Scrapy the usual way:
Python 2, pip, pip install Scrapy

I read that Python3, Windows10 and 64bit are not so good for Scrapy so I've installed 32bit Ubuntu to Oracle Virtualbox. I've also followed the advice of codereviewvideos and applied:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf libtool pkg-config python-opengl python-imaging python-pyrex python-pyside.qtopengl idle-python2.7 qt4-dev-tools qt4-designer libqtgui4 libqtcore4 libqt4-xml libqt4-test libqt4-script libqt4-network libqt4-dbus python-qt4 python-qt4-gl libgle3 python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python-dev lib32z1-dev build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev python-dev
```

https://codereviewvideos.com/blog/scrapy-1-1-ubuntu-15-10/

...but still throws error code 1 about lxml and the installation apt-gethas thrown: unable to locate package lib32z1-dev

Comment: I believe you are missing lxml package. please try installing it and run the above command and see. For installing [lxml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you used won't work on windows....
have you try to follow indication to install scrapy on windows :

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.10.3/intro/install.html#intro-install-step3

And also you should install lxml :
`pip install lxml`

`Scrapy` need other packages, you will find the list here :

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html

on windows it's recommended to use conda  (https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install)

*"Though it’s possible to install Scrapy on Windows using pip, we recommend you to install Anaconda or Miniconda and use the package from the conda-forge channel, which will avoid most installation issues."*

Comment: Thanks. 
I've managed to install Scrapy with sudo apt install python scrapy on Ubuntu.
Now I'm installing Conda on Windows.

Comment: so it's solved ? but you should be able to make it work on windows too !

Comment: Yes, thanks. With Conda I've managed to do it. Pip is not enough any more.